# how to combine result of stored procedure which returns two results in SQL 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Hey i'm kind new in Stored procs, i have procedure like

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[list_of_employee]
(
  @employee_id int
 )
 as 
begin 
select *from project_employee_rel PE
inner join employee_details E on E.employee_id=PE.employee_id
inner join project_details P on P.project_id=PE.project_id 
where PE.employee_id=@employee_id

select * from employee_details 
where employee_id=@employee_id
end
```

It returns two results separately 
I want result like 'if first query returns empty rows or null then second query get executed otherwise not
Plz help me
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12715687/137615

Comment: The two queries have different result schemas, are you sure this is what you want? If you branch the code as you suggest, different `@employee_id`s will use widely different query plans, the structure of you results will vary depending on the value you supply ... The SP will be a performance burden instead of a performance benefit.

Comment: i don't want to lower the perfomance of sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[list_of_employee]
(
  @employee_id int
)
as 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Count int
  SET @Count = select COUNT(PRIMARYKEY COLUMN) from project_employee_rel PE
    inner join employee_details E on E.employee_id=PE.employee_id
    inner join project_details P on P.project_id=PE.project_id 
    where PE.employee_id=@employee_id
  IF (@Count>0)
   BEGIN
      select *from project_employee_rel PE
       inner join employee_details E on E.employee_id=PE.employee_id
       inner join project_details P on P.project_id=PE.project_id 
       where PE.employee_id=@employee_id
   END

  ELSE
   BEGIN
       select * from employee_details 
       where employee_id=@employee_id
   END
END
```

Comment: hey thank u that's what i want.
to improve sp performance i figured out also another solution using left outer joins

Comment: ok, thats good, i just given answer for what you want, if it is help full for you, up vote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Check Count of your first query
  return result set
ELSE 
  return other result set
END
```