# Call SQL Sever system stored procedures with query language?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL SERVER. And I am wondering can the system stored procedures (e.g., sp_help) can be called with query language such as select and where?

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Comment: You have the short answer. The longer answer is that you cannot reference a stored procedure directly in a SELECT statement. That applies to any stored procedure - those that are system and supplied by MS and those that you write.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the results in a table and then filter out the records:

e.g.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        SPID INT,
        Status VARCHAR(MAX),
        LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX),
        HostName VARCHAR(MAX),
        BlkBy VARCHAR(MAX),
        DBName VARCHAR(MAX),
        Command VARCHAR(MAX),
        CPUTime INT,
        DiskIO INT,
        LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX),
        ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX),
        SPID_1 INT,
        REQUESTID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_who2

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234691/sql-server-filter-output-of-sp-who2)

Sp_help returns more than one result sets. The following link might be helpful in that case:

[**Store multiple result sets**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383465/how-to-save-result-of-sp-help-tablename-in-user-tables)

[**Retrieve a single result set**](https://tsqlt.org/201/using-tsqlt-resultsetfilter/)