# Executing a multiline SQL statement in one string in C# program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is it possible in C# to execute multiline SQL statement in one call without creating Stored Procedure with this SQL?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
string mySQL = "with CTE_table as (....)" +
               "select name from CTE_table where ...." ;

_sql_Command = _sql_conn.CreateCommand();
_sql_Command.CommandText = mySQL ;
SqlDataReader dataReader = _sql_Command.ExecuteReader();

if (dataReader.Read())
{
...
```

I found a suggestion to separate SQL by ";", in this case I am getting a syntax error

Thanks,

zb

Comment: Show your sql, you can separate statements with `;`

Comment: Look at this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715620/how-do-i-return-multiple-result-sets-with-sqlcommand

Comment: When you do this, you need to fetch the results separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715620/how-do-i-return-multiple-result-sets-with-sqlcommand.  You can also use Dapper, and it has a "QueryMultiple" extension method

Comment: That is a single statement. `WITH` is a clause of the `SELECT` statement.  The select won't work without the first, and the first without the second is also a syntax error.  You most likely are missing the space between them which is causing a syntax error.

Comment: Edited question to reflect the correct question.

Comment: Don't forget that you wouldn't want to execute a straight SQL statement like this without parameterized `WHERE` clause. SQL Injection will make your day very long and un-fun.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 var mySQL = @"with CTE_table as (....) 
             select name from CTE_table where ...." ;
```

sometimes I find this approach handy

```
   var whereclause = "....";
   var mySQL = $@"with CTE_table as (....) 
                 select name from CTE_table where {whereclause}" ;
```

Answer (score -2):

I changed my SQL to one SQL without using "WITH CTE" and now with one SQL it is working.
zb

Comment: Kirsten Greed's answers below should both work because you are just missing a white space  character, and both of her answers correctly include a white space character in them.