# How to get Remaining outputs from stored procedure with multiple returns in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am calling a stored procedure from my desktop app and that stored procedure returns multiple results.

But when I store the result into a DataTable, only the very 1st results is filled.
Can someone help me out with this.

The stored procedure that I used is:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoUserLogsAndImageArchive]
    @UserName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @CompUserName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @CompName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @DateTime NVARCHAR(50),
    @EAN NVARCHAR(50), 
    @Path NVARCHAR(50),
    @FileName NVARCHAR(50),
    @BatchId NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ULId NVARCHAR(50), @AId NVARCHAR(50)

    INSERT INTO [UserLogs] (UserName, CompUserName, CompName, DateTime) OUTPUT INSERTED.ULId --into @ULId 
    VALUES (@UserName, @CompUserName, @CompName, @DateTime);

    SELECT @ULId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO [ImagesArchive] (EAN, Path, FileName, BatchId, ULId) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.AId 
    VALUES (@EAN, @Path, @FileName, @BatchId, @ULId);

    SELECT @AId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SELECT ULId, AId 
    FROM ImagesArchive 
    WHERE AId = @AId;
END
```

And the code snippet to receive data is:

```cs
public DataTable ExecuteQuery2(string storedProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> param)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(""))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param.ToArray());                    

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Executing the stored procedure returns following:

[image: Image of output]

I want to get the very last result in my DataTable instead of the 1st one.  Although I have other options but I really want to go with this.

Please help!

Comment: If Image is not clearly visible, please open it in new tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple result sets with SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715620/how-do-i-return-multiple-result-sets-with-sqlcommand)

Comment: The return value from the same  query will always return same results.  Which means either you are querying a different database or the AId in the WHERE is wrong.  Like in one place you are using an string and the other place an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `datatable` you may use `dataset`. So you updated code in c# will be

```
public DataSet ExecuteQuery2(string storedProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> param)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(""))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param.ToArray());                    

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

By this way you may return all of the records return from your procedure.

Or

If you want to send particular `DataTable`, then you may update like this.

```
public DataTable ExecuteQuery2(string storedProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> param)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(""))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param.ToArray());                    

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }

    return ds.Tables[0];   //// here instead of 0 you may pass the table number you want to return
}
```

Comment: I surely missed that one. Your solution solves my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a datareader

```
datatable1.Load(reader)
reader.NextResult();
datatable2.Load(reader)
```

to get your next table of data.

This should allow you to hit each result set in turn.

Comment: And use `DataTable.Load` to load a DataTable from each result. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netframework-4.8