# Stored Procedure with Multiple Select Statements

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OpsToolStats]    Script Date: 09/05/2023 
09:21:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author, , Name>
-- Create Date: <Create Date, , >
-- Description: <Description, , >
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OpsToolStats]
(
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT count([EndCustomerOrderId]) AS NewOrdersNeedsLabels
FROM [dbo].[EndCustomerOrders]
where ([StatusId] = 0 or [StatusId] = 1000) and CreatedAt >= @startDate and  [CreatedAt] 
<= @endDate

SELECT count([EndCustomerOrderId]) AS APIErrorCeatingLabels
FROM [dbo].[EndCustomerOrders]
where [StatusId] = 1100 and CreatedAt >= @startDate and  [CreatedAt] <= @endDate

SELECT count([EndCustomerOrderId]) AS ScheduleCollection
FROM [dbo].[EndCustomerOrders]
where ([StatusId] = 1300 or [StatusId] = 1500 or [StatusId] = 1700) and CreatedAt >= 
@startDate and  [CreatedAt] <= @endDate

END
```

In SQL Enterprise manager the results visually look like this:

[image]

I am trying to work out how to call this SP and get the results of the individual select statements:

I have the following code:

```
var command = _dbLive.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "OpsToolStats";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", "2023-05-01"));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", "2023-05-31"));

        _dbLive.Database.OpenConnection();

        using var result = command.ExecuteReader();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(result);
```

But I only get 1 column and 1 row in the datatable... for the "NewOrdersNeedsLabels"..

Can anyone suggest how to get all the values please?

Comment: You are returning multiple result sets but you are only consuming the *first* result set in your C# code. Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple result sets with SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715620/how-do-i-return-multiple-result-sets-with-sqlcommand)

Comment: Though, in  truth, considering all your queries are against `dbo.EndCustomerOrders` I'm not sure why you don't return a single data set with many columns. It'll likely be far more performant.

Comment: Looks like you could combine them into one query `SELECT count(case when StatusId IN (0, 1000) then EndCustomerOrderId end), count(case when StatusId IN (1100) then EndCustomerOrderId end)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're using `DataTable.Load` which only loads the first resultset - it will ignore subsequent resultsets.
- Instead, use a `DataSet` object (which itself contains multiple `DataTable` objects: one for each resultsset): as `DataSet.Load` *will* attempt to consume all resultsets from a `DbDataReader` for you.
- If you're using `SqlDataReader` directly (instead of letting `DataTable.Load`, `DataSet.Load` or `SqlDataAdapter`  do all the hard work for you) then you will need to call `NextResult()` *after* you finish your `while( rdr.Read() )` loop for the first result-set - and then have separate `while( rdr.Read() )` loops for all *expected* subsequent results.

  - It is important that you always check if `NextResult()` returns `true` or `false` and put the effort in to gracefully handle unexpecedly fewer actualk resultsets (this can happen if your `PROCEDURE` or statement-batch errors out.

So this, basically:

- Also:

  - **Always** specify exact `SqlDbType` values for every `SqlParameter` because ADO.NET's type-inference is unhelpfully simplistic.
  - Where-possible (i.e. on .NET 7+ with the latest `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` library) when using SQL Server's `date` for parameters you should use .NET's `DateOnly` value type instead of `DateTime` - and especially not date-string-literals - your current code as-is right now *could* potentially misbehave if thread culture/localization settings align with the stars.

```
SqlConnection c = _dbLive.Database.GetDbConnection();

SqlCommand command = c.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "OpsToolStats";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = new DateOnly( 2023, 5, 1 ) );
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = new DateOnly( 2023, 5, 31 ) );

if( c.State != ConnectionState.Open ) c.OpenConnection();

using( SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader() ) )
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Load( rdr );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for the pointers.. this is what i ended up with:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_config["ConnectionStringLive"]))
        {
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("OpsToolStats", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", "2023-05-01"));
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", "2023-05-31"));
            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            Sherpr.Model.Model.Calendar.BucketStats stats = new Sherpr.Model.Model.Calendar.BucketStats
            {
                NewOrdersNeedsLabels = (int)dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0].Table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]
            };

        }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `SqlDataAdapter` at all here - it's unnecessary as `DataSet` and `DataTable` are capable of populating themselves from a `DbDataReader` without the need for a `DataAdapter` (`DataAdapter` exists to help with two-way updatable data operations - which your code doesn't seem to be performing, therefore there is no reason to use it here).