# Casting with Type object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I want to use GetType() method to get the Type of the variable then cast some other variable to this type. For example, I have an Int32 i, a Double d, I want to get Type of d (in general case) then cast i to d's Type then grant i's value to d.

```
Int32 i = 123;
Double d = 0.0;
Type t = d.GetType();
d = Conversion.CastExamp1 < t > (i);
d = Conversion.ConvertExamp1 < t > (i);
```

PS: @Zyphrax: i have used your post here
[Casting a variable using a Type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable) but when compiling, it says that "The type or namespace name 't' could not be found...". So could you please describe more detail how to use your code?

Comment: casting is tricky to do properly at runtime.

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: I think you're a level too high here. With generics (the `<T>`) you can simply do `Conversion.CastExamp1<Double>(i);`

Comment: You're not casting here.  Casting means changing the type of the variable that references an object *without changing the object itself in any way*.  You want to convert the object, which is something entirely different.

Comment: Why do you want to do this.  It seems like a generally poor idea here.  If we knew what your underlying problem is we may be able to suggest a preferable approach to solving it without needing to solve this particular problem at all.

Comment: It is not really clear why you would need this. With `t` and `i` as above, as long as you have `IConvertible` types, you can probably use `object result = Convert.ChangeType(i, t);` but as I said I am not sure it is useful. Consider `double result = i;`.

Comment: In case I dont know exactly type of variable d at run-time but I know that type is some kind of number (i.e: float or double or decimal, etc), and I want to cast value of variable i to assign to d. The .NET provides GetType() method to get type of d, so I want to use this Type object to cast the value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Type` as a generic parameter, this must be an object that can be constructed which `Type`cannot. The closes you will get is by using objects as parameters

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 i = 123;
            Double d = 0.0;
            Type t = d.GetType();

            // Print the type of d
            Console.WriteLine(t.Name); // "Double"

            var newI = DoStuff(t, i);

            // Print the new type of i
            Console.WriteLine(newI.GetType().Name); // "Double"
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static object DoStuff(object type, object inData)
        {
            Type newType = (Type)type;

            // Fix nullables...
            Type newNullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(newType) ?? newType;

            // ...and change the type
            return Convert.ChangeType(inData, newNullableType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my idea is that I want to separate my program into 2 layer: 1 layer for UI which get user input with some type (i.e: Int32), 1 layer for DB interaction. In DB interact layer, I want to re-use it for multiple DB, for some DB I dont know exactly type mapping between it and .NET. So I need some ways to get .NET type of DB to cast data from UI layer passes to.

Comment: please follow the link in my post, may be help you understand my idea more