# How can I cast to a given Type?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I'm trying to figure out how I can do something along the lines of

```
Type t = Type.GetType("fully qualified type name");
dynamic obj = foo as t
```

How do I do this?  I was looking at `Convert.ChangeType()`, but that just returns an object and that's not what I want.

Comment: This is a similar question, but if you look at the marked answer's comments, it doesn't solve the question.  It only solved it for whatever that other person was trying to do.

Comment: @Lynx, yup, My bad.  that is why I decided to reopen it.

Comment: @Habib, I assume you are referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable.  This does seem to be a direct duplicate... If that question does not cover your use case, please post a more complete example.

Comment: How is this useful in any situation? What would you do with `obj` now that you have cast it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? What type is foo and is it actually a `t`? Or are you trying to have the runtime magically convert a representation in one type to some arbitrary other type?

Comment: @Mitch The difference is that `T` is (presumably) not known at compile-time

Comment: @DStanley, I agree, but if you do not have a compile-time known type, what is the problem with getting something of type `object`?

Comment: @Mitch It's not a problem; I was just explaining why that question is not an exact duplicate

Comment: Sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The `Type` is resolved at run time based on parameters supplied in a database table.  So the type of t is defined in one of the classes, but not immediately known at compile time.

Comment: @Lunyx If you don't know what the type will be how are you going to call methods or access properties?

Comment: @Lunyx - okay so you know the type at runtime, and you casted the underlying type of the dynamic to it. Now what can you do with that? What was the point?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are mixing disciplines, and I don't understand why.  Either use reflection or dynamic typing, but using both makes little sense to me.

If you are doing something with types you control, have them implement an interface:

```
interface IModule
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class Module1 : IModule
{
    public string Name { get { return "Module 1"; } } 
}

public void PrintModuleName(string moduleType)
{
    Type tModule = Type.GetType("MyApp.Module1");
    IModule module = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(tModule);
    Console.WriteLine(module.Name); 
}
```

If you are working with types you don't control, use `dynamic` - no cast needed:

```
class Module1
{
    public string Name { get { return "Module 1"; } } 
}

public void PrintModuleName(string moduleType)
{
    Type tModule = Type.GetType("MyApp.Module1");
    dynamic module = Activator.CreateInstance(tModule);
    Console.WriteLine(module.Name); 
}
```

The only case where I could see the cast being necessary is for COM interop as a substitute for `QueryInterface` or if the type implements a cast which returns a new object.

---

Regarding your comment:

> Since `Convert.ChangeType()` returns a type of object, wouldn't `obj` still
>   resolve to a type of object during runtime? How does this differ from
>   `object obj = Convert.ChangeType(foo,t);`? To my understanding, the
>   `dynamic` keyword still uses the same type

Static typing specifies the *most restricted* type you are allowed to access in code.  For example, you have a variable `t` typed as `System.Type` in the statement `Type t = Type.GetType("foo");`, but at runtime, `GetType` will return a value of type `System.RuntimeType`.  Since `System.RuntimeType` inherits from `System.Type`, it is not a problem.

Similarly, everything* inherits from `System.Object` and can be stored in a variable typed as `object`.  An example may be helpful:

```
System.Type t = Type.GetType("System.String");
Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `t`:\t{0}", t.GetType().FullName);
// Prints "Runtime type of `t` is: System.RuntimeType"

System.String s = "foo";
Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `s`:\t{0}", s.GetType().FullName);
// Prints "Runtime type of `s` is: System.String"

object o = s;
Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `o`:\t{0}", o.GetType().FullName);
// Prints "Runtime type of `o` is: System.String"
```

Dynamic is syntactic sugar for Reflection, and therefore does not exist as a separate type.  So:

```
string s = "foo";
Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `s`:\t{0}", s.GetType().FullName);
// Prints "Runtime type of `s` is: System.String"

dynamic d = s;
Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `d:\t{0}", d.GetType().FullName);
// Also prints "Runtime type of `d` is: System.String"
```

Is the same as:

```
string s = "foo";
Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `s`:\t{0}", s.GetType().FullName);

Type typeOfS = s.GetType();
object resultOfGetType = typeOfS.GetMethod("GetType").Invoke(s, null);
Type typeOfResultOfGetType = resultOfGetType.GetType();
object resultOfFullName = typeOfResultOfGetType.GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(resultOfGetType);

Console.WriteLine("Runtime type of `d:\t{0}", resultOfFullName);
```

The C# just generates all of this code** at compile-time.

<sub>*: well... [most everything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx)</sub>
<sub>**: well... [not exactly this code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `as` since it requires the type to be known at compile-time.  Since you're already using `dynamic` why not just do:

```
dynamic obj = Convert.ChangeType(foo, t);
```

The return type of the `Convert.ChangeType` method is `object`, but the actual type of the underlying object will be `t`, so you can still use it's methods and properties dynamically.

Comment: Since `Convert.ChangeType()` returns a type of object, wouldn't obj still resolve to a type of object during runtime? How does this differ from `object obj = Convert.ChangeType(foo,t);`? To my understanding, the dynamic keyword still uses the same type.

Comment: @Lunyx dynamic only turns off compile time type checking. `obj` is at runtime whatever type `ChangeType` returned in both cases.

Comment: @Lunyx No, otherwise `ChangeType` would be pointless (you'd just get a vanilla object back).  The _design time_ type of the object will be `object`, but the _actual_ type would be `t` (meaning you could use reflection or `dynamic` to get to the members of type `t`).

Comment: If that's the case, then I've been misunderstanding what actually happens when the dynamic keyword is used. I'll give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: @Lunyx to your second question, a `dynamic` is NOT just an `object` - the actual object will have a runtime type; it just defers binding of properties and methods to run-time (which was previously only possible through reflection).

Comment: @DStanley I was thinking that in this specific case, dynamic would resolve to object since the return type of Convert.ChangeType is of type object.

Comment: No, that's just the _design-time_ type - it can in reality be any type.  Just list iterating an `ArrayList` returns `object`s, but the _actual_ type is probably something else.  If you looked at it in the debugger you would see that it;s not _just_ an `object`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on everything. The object must implement IConvertible interface.

Comment: @Lunyx If you're not actually converting the type (meaning the object is _already_ of that type) you can just do `dynamic obj = t`.