# c# - Cast with GetType() and reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

So after implemented `Page Object Pattern` using [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/software-engineering-best-practices/getting-started-with-page-object-pattern-for-your-selenium-tests) tutorial i have several 
Pages that derived from `BasePageElementMap`.

And i want to handle some operation so i have this class:

```
public class DownloadAttachmentsHandler
    {
        public DownloadAttachmentsHandler(BasePageElementMap basePageElementMap)
        {
            Type type = basePageElementMap.GetType();            
        }
    }
```

Every `Pages` that derived from `BasePageElementMap` have this `html` elements that locate inside its class that derived from `BasePageElementMap` and from this `Page` i have this `Map` object that contains all my `HTML` elements that i am using.

```
public class YahooEmailPage: BasePage<YahooEmailPageElementMap, YahooEmailPageValidator>...
```

so in case i am call this function like this:

```
UploadAttachmentsHandler att = new UploadAttachmentsHandler(new YahooEmailPage().Map);
```

I want to cast this into `YahooEmailPage` from my `DownloadAttachmentsHandler` method.

So currently i have this `type` object, how can i case it into `YahooEmailPage` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting a variable using a Type variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable)

Comment: Can I have code example how to use it?

Comment: Just to clarify, which variable do you want to cast into the Type `type`?

Comment: I sent to the function this which is object that derived from BasePageElementMap, the function gets BasePageElementMap and I want to cast it into the derived object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the following:

```
public class DownloadAttachmentsHandler
{
    public static object Cast(object obj, Type t)
    { 
        try
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType());
            return Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(param, t), param)
                 .Compile().DynamicInvoke(obj);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
             throw ex.InnerException;
        }         
    }


    public DownloadAttachmentsHandler(BasePageElementMap basePageElementMap)
    {
        Type type = basePageElementMap.GetType();
        dynamic foo = Cast(basePageElementMap, type);
    }
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380177/7662085) answer by balage.

**EDIT:** For the example, lets assume that `GetType()` returns the type `bar`. You will have to create a method like this one:

```
public static void UseDynamic(bar input)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

And then do

```
public DownloadAttachmentsHandler(BasePageElementMap basePageElementMap)
{
    Type type = basePageElementMap.GetType();
    dynamic foo = Cast(basePageElementMap, type);
    UseDynamic(foo);
}
```

You can use overloads to avoid having to write many `if`s or a switch. However, whichever approach you take, you will have to create a method for each possible type.

Comment: OK thats fine, i can see that foo is the type i expected but how to see all my functions inside this? how to auto cast it to the correct type ?

Comment: You will have to call another method that takes an argument of the expected type, and pass `foo` to it.

Comment: I am sorry but i did not understand how to implement it, can you sow me please short example ?

Comment: Thats mean that is i have 100 different types that derived i need 100 methods ?

Comment: Not if they all inherit from 2 or 3 types and the methods of said types are the only ones you need.

Comment: They all inherit from this BasePageElementMap  class, but you said "whichever approach you take, you will have to create a method for each possible type", i have YahooEmailPage, GmailEmailPage and several more (as i mention they all inherit from BasePageElementMap  )

Comment: If you need to use any methods that BasePageElementMap doesnt have, you will have to create a separate method. If not, then there is no need to do the cast in the first place.

Comment: unfortunately  i need to use methods that BasePageElementMap doesnt have but only in the son class so the only way is to create simple switch\if ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143901/discussion-between-sty-and-user979033).