# How do I convert a dynamically typed object to a type argument <T> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, casting

I've googled for hours and also found various stackoverflow questions but none cater to my exact use-case. This is what I have: a method that takes 2 generic type parameters. The library is closed source so I cannot modify it. The method signature looks like:

```
 TTo Convert<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom obj)
```

However when you call this you always have to provide both type parameters, like this:

```
Convert<Dog, Cat>(dog);
```

I'm trying to support a use-case where only the destination type parameter is provided:

```
Convert<Cat>(dog);
```

So the method signature I need is as follows:

```
TTo Convert<TTo>(object obj){
     var TFrom = obj.GetType();
     Convert<TFrom, TTo>((TFrom)obj); // <--- throws an error right here
}
```

Can you help me fix this? This SO answer mentions using [Lambda expression builders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893484/9009598) but I'm not sure how to do that in this use case. This SO answer mentions [dynamic typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable) but its not what I need here.

**Edit:** The [linked "duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class) comes close but it only handles dynamically casting generic types for regular method arguments, but doesn't handle TYPE arguments which is what I need.

Comment: You have bigger problems than casting. You can't use `TFrom` as a generic type parameter, which makes this a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with Reflection.
You just need to construct a method with your type parameters applied.

```
class Program
{

    public static TTo Convert<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I was called with {obj}");
        return default;
    }

    public static TTo ConvertObject<TTo>(object obj)
    {
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Convert));
        var specialized = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { obj.GetType(), typeof(TTo) });
        return (TTo) specialized.Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ConvertObject<int>(1.0f); //prints I was called with 1
```

The `null` is passed because the method was static; that should be substituted with the instance which contains the `Convert` method, as well as the type containing the method.

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Those close votes really inspired me to answer this. ;)

Comment: You're awesome. Keep being awesome!