# How to cast IQueryable<object>/IEnumerable<object> to a given Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a collection (`IQueryable<object>/IEnumerable<object>`) and a given `Type` that I get by reflection at runtime. How can I cast the `IQueryable<object>` to the specific `Type` when:

1. The `Type` is a class e.g. `Person` (and I want to make a cast of the `IQueryable<object>` to `IQueryable<Person>`)
2. The `Type` is a generic collection e.g. `IQueryable<Person>`

Note that Type is a variable that I get through aVariable.GetType(). I do not know the type beforehand, therefore I cannot use `Cast<type>` nor (type).

Comment: `.OfType<...>()`?

Comment: .Select(x => (YourType) x)

Comment: @MohammadHamoud the Type is a variable that I get through object.GetType()

Comment: @Midas Something seems weird about this. Can you add more details about your flow?

Comment: They invented generics for this reasons

Comment: Can't you use generic functions?

Comment: Check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145562/6629297

Comment: @MohammadHamoud If I knew the type beforehand yes. In this case I get the type at runtime through GetType().

Comment: @Midas But how do you hope to use the result if you don't know the type at compile time, or through using generics?

Comment: @john I want to use it in dynamic linq. The reason I want to convert it is out of the scope of the question (it would complicate things and I want to keep it clean).

Comment: Midas [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @john I will need some time and I will get back about this.

Comment: @MohammadHamoud, that seems to be the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: @Midas please mark my answer as accepted in order for others to know when passing this question by

Comment: Let's imagine you have converted `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<Person>` using reflection. How will you use it? What is the sense in a collection of a type known at runtime only?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: I intend to use it in a dynamic linq query. When it was left unconverted, the query gave error on fields that were actually there. When it gets converted the query executes without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If targeted type is known, go with this

```
yourIEnumerable.Select(x => (YourType) x);
```

But as you noted, you don't know the type of the targeted type and you are getting it using `object.GetType()` so I would recommend to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145562/6629297) link