# How to convert a variable type to another variable type

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I have an object array which all has been filled with specific command arguments (of type `string`):

```
object[] args = {"@all", "1", "true"};
```

And I have this method:

```
public void Method(string client, int num, bool type)<br/>
```

I want to pass the arguments specified in the object array to the method. How can I convert each object array element to the specific types expected by the method?

**Note:** The method parameter types **ARE NOT FIXED**, so I need to convert the items in the object array to different types that are unknown at compile time.

Line 49 format error:
https://pastebin.com/bQLsbs59

Comment: This is the purpose of [Casting variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable)

Comment: Sounds like a possible use case for reflection; though the whole thing smells like an XY problem

Comment: Are you ultimately just trying to invoke a function by using a list of objects as the functions arguments?

Comment: you can use `MethodInfo.Invoke` from the Reflection namespace. it comes with a performance penalty, but takes an `object[]` so you could pass your parameters directly. The requirement for argument order and overload selections apply just like they would in compile-time call overload resolution. [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dlatikay ikr, I am using MethodInfo.Invoke to invoke method. now the problem is that all of my object elements' type are string data type because all of those is apart of string. All I want is those type of element can be automatically convert to Method parameter type.

Comment: Why is args not string[]?  You cannot parse on Object to Int.  At best you would call Object.ToString() and hope it parses.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Look at line 49:
https://pastebin.com/bQLsbs59

I want each type of element of object array can be automatically convert to MethodInfo's parameter type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MethodInfo` to get the parameters for a method.  Then with the `ParameterInfo` you can get the type of that parameter.  Then the final step is to use `Convert` to change the type of each string to the correct type.

```
object[] args = { "@all", "1", "true" };

MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Form1).GetMethod("Method");
ParameterInfo[] paramInfos = methodInfo.GetParameters();

// Should check that args.Length == paramInfos.Length.

// The arguments converted to their correct types will go in here.
object[] convertedArgs = new object[args.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
  // Should do a try/catch here in-case the string can't be
  // converted to the parameter type. i.e. trying to convert
  // "abc" to an int.

  // Change each string to the appropriate type.
  convertedArgs[i] = Convert.ChangeType(args[i],
    paramInfos[i].ParameterType);
}

// Finally, we can call the method with the arguments that have
// been converted to the correct types.
methodInfo.Invoke(this, convertedArgs);
```