# return class instead of interface from collection holding interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-component-system

I want to create a small Entity-Component-System example and created some components like

```
internal struct Position : IComponent
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
internal struct MovementSpeed : IComponent
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Every component implements a currently empty interface `IComponent`. When the system is looping through the entities I would like to find the relevant components fast.

I thought about creating a Dictionary that holds the component type as the key and the component of the current entity as the value.

I started with `public Dictionary<Type, IComponent> Components { get; }`

I can add components using `myEntity.Components.Add(typeof(Movement), new Movement() as IComponent);`

but how can I return a component? I created a movement-system example

```
internal class Movement : ISystem
{
    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (Entity entity in EntityPool.activeEntities.Values) // Loop through all entities
        {
            Dictionary<Type, IComponent> components = entity.Components;

            if (components.TryGetValue(typeof(Position), out Position positionComponent))
            {
                if (components.TryGetValue(typeof(MovementSpeed), out MovementSpeed movementSpeedComponent))
                {
                    // TEST: move (1 * movementspeed) units
                    positionComponent.X += movementSpeedComponent.Value;
                    positionComponent.Y += movementSpeedComponent.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`if (components.TryGetValue(typeof(Position), out Position positionComponent))` crashes because the value of the dictionary does not return the component of desired Type itself, it returns the interface.

How can I make it work?

*(Yeah I know I could use a ECS framework but I would like to do it on my own for learning purposes)*

Comment: You'd need to use reflection to find and get the value of the specified member. A much better approach would be to put the members in your interface. I'm not sure I get what you're doing but that is kind of the purpose of using interfaces.

Comment: Why do you have nested `if` s ?

Comment: @JonathanWood would you mind explaining it a little bit more?

Comment: @Fabjan because this system should only update entities that have a position and a movementspeed component attached

Comment: Probably not. Especially since you didn't even clarify what *it* is.

Comment: Retrieve it from the dictionary as an `IComponent` and then cast it to a `Position`. Since you are only pulling `Positions`, the cast should always succeed (though I'd use `is` or `as` to make sure and prevent an `InvalidCastException`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: You can't. If dictionary is of type `Dictionary<Type, IComponent>` then it will return only `IComponent`.

However you could create an extension method for this:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TComponent GetValueOrNull<TComponent>(this Dictionary<Type, IComponent> dict) where TComponent : IComponent
    {
        dict.TryGetValue(typeof(TComponent), out IComponent component);
        return component as TComponent;
    } 
}
```

And use it:

```
internal class Movement : ISystem
{
    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (Entity entity in EntityPool.activeEntities.Values) // Loop through all entities
        {
            var posComponent = entity.Components.GetValueOrNull<Position>();

            if (posComponent != null)
            {
                // some code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but just be aware that there is a more general convention with TryGet.... methods. These tend to return a bool (true if it got it and false if not there), and returns the actual value as an out parameter. (See Dictionary<T> for an example, but even the various things like int.TryParse() is basically the same convention).

Comment: Yeah, I've changed the name to GetValueOrNull

Comment: I know there is hard to reach the result but does he is really out of chance? What about this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable especially dynamic keyword. Bad side of that solution will be slow performace in runtime and there is very big limitation of manipulation with objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert an item of type IComponent, you can only retrievee the item as IComponent.
If you ask the Dictionary for a specific type, you can cast to the type directly.

```
        foreach (Entity entity in EntityPool) // Loop through all entities
        {
            Dictionary<Type, IComponent> components = entity.Components;
            if (components.TryGetValue(typeof(Position), out IComponent positionComponent))
            {
                Position position = (Position)positionComponent;
                if (components.TryGetValue(typeof(MovementSpeed), out IComponent movementSpeedComponent))
                {
                    MovementSpeed speed = (MovementSpeed)movementSpeedComponent;
                    // TEST: move (1 * movementspeed) units
                    position.X += speed.Value;
                    position.Y += speed.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

With linq you have a very efficient way, to operate on a list. Perhaps is this a better way for you. Here is an example:

```
    public void Update2()
    {
        List<IComponent> list = new List<IComponent>();
        list.OfType<Position>().ToList().ForEach(p =>
        {
            var speed = list.OfType<MovementSpeed?>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (speed.HasValue)
            {
                p.X = speed.Value.Value;
                p.Y = speed.Value.Value;
            }
        });
    }
```