# Integrate function (and their types) from Python to C#

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

My goal is to convert a Python function to a function in C# with the same functionality. The important aspect here is that I have information in Python on the input types and output types of the function. This information should be transferred to the function in C#.

Using IronPython I can integrate the Python function to C# with `object` as input and output types. Currently I have the following code:

```
    class Program 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
                "def Add(arg1, arg2):\n" +
                "   return arg1 +1\n"  +
                "\n" +
                "functionTypes = int" +
                "\n" +
                "class MyClass(object):\n" +
                "   def __init__(self, value):\n" +
                "       self.value = value\n");
        source.Execute(scope);

        var Add= scope.GetVariable<Func<object, object , object>>("Add");
        Console.WriteLine(Add(2,3 ));
```

But what I would like to have is `var Add= scope.GetVariable<Func<functionTypes, functionTypes , functionTypes>>("Add");` where functionTypes represents int.

EDIT: Is there a solution which works for functions with arbitrary inputs. For instance, we want to translate an arbirtary function in python to the same function in c# (including all the types)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with it is using a manual casting. You can get C# clr type from IronPython using **clr**() method, then you can create if statement to create specific Func type [(like in this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972653/4510954). You can also try to find a C# reflection solution [(read this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable) but in case of making Func<yourType, yourType, yourType> it could be extremly hard.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var scope = engine.CreateScope();
    var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
            "def Add(arg1, arg2):\n" +
            "   return arg1 +1\n" +
            "\n" +
            "functionTypes = int" +
            "\n" +
            "class MyClass(object):\n" +
            "   def __init__(self, value):\n" +
            "       self.value = value\n");
    source.Execute(scope);
    var type = scope.GetVariable("functionTypes") as IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType;
    Type clrType = type.__clrtype__();
    if (clrType == typeof(int))
    {
        var Add = scope.GetVariable<Func<int, int, int>>("Add");
        Console.WriteLine(Add(2, 3));
    }
    else if (clrType == typeof(double))
    {
        var Add = scope.GetVariable<Func<double, double, double>>("Add");
        Console.WriteLine(Add(2, 3));
    }
    //make your own else statements here
}
```

Comment: This approach works fairly well in the example I gave above. But let's assume we have an arbitrary function with arbitrary arguments in python. And we want to extract this function from the python script. Do you see a solution for that?

Comment: You can get by: var func = scope.GetVariable("Add"); , but you need to know type if you want to parse in C#, instead you only get dynamic type. Anyway, I think you can try reflection but I also think it will be very hard in case of function extraction.